# How to check unknown number of booleans c#

Tags: c#, unity3d-editor

I need to check unknown number of booleans.. depending on the result it will do the appropriate function.
Here is example of what I'm searching:

```
if(bool[x] && bool[y] && bool[z] ...)
   myFunc();
```

Comment: If x,y,z are ordered you could do it in for loop for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `LINQ` for that.

If you need all the bools to be true, you can use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb337697%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (bools.All(b => b))
```

If you need, for example, 4 of them exactly to be true, you can use [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb337697%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (bools.Count(b => b) == 4)
```

Or at least one, there's [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb337697%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if (bools.Any(b => b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ function `All()`:

```
var all = bool.All(x=>x == true);
if(all)
    myFunc();
```

or simply

```
var all = bool.All(x=>x);
if(all)
    myFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var all=true;
for (var i=x; i<z; i++) if (!bool[i]) {all=false; break;}
if (all) myFunc()
```

or, if `x, y, z` are not sequential, put them in the list or array:

```
int[] indices = new [] {x, y, z};
```

and then iterate like this:

```
var all=true;
foreach (var i in indices) if (!bool[i]) {all=false; break;}
if (all) myFunc()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (bool.Any(m => !m)
{
    // At least one bool is false
}
else
{
    // All bools are true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) to check that all the values meet the predicate.

`if(bool.All())`